# Правильно ли я расставил знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Водитель предложил остановиться у него за небольшую плату. Зашел в избу — семья не маленькая: нет, лучше пойду в гостиницу.

Answer (score 2):

***Водитель предложил остановиться у него за небольшую плату. Зашел в избу (и увидел): семья не маленькая - (так что) нет, лучше пойду в гостиницу.***

Предлагаю такой вариант знаков. Двоеточие ставим на месте "и увидел", а третье предложение имеет значение следствия, поэтому на месте союза "так что" ставим тире.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант:

***Водитель предложил остановиться у него за небольшую плату. Зашел в избу — семья не маленькая... Нет, лучше пойду в гостиницу.***

Comment: Наиболее оптимальный вариант, полностью соответствует интонации для данного содержания.  Тире  заменяет двоеточие в нераспространенных предложениях разной структуры (нет увеличенной паузы), а вот пауза перед "нет" явно присутствует, многоточие обозначает "раздумье" перед выбором решения.